# Spotfire - Difference of IDs over years

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have a dataset like this: a 3 year employees list with some employees that are present in all three years (ID:1,2,3), some that joined/left the company in different years.

```
Year IDEmployee
2014 1
2014 2
2014 3
2014 4
2015 1
2015 2
2015 3
2015 5
2015 6
2016 1
2016 2
2016 3
2016 6
2016 7
2016 8
```

I need to calculate the in/out fluxes for all the periods (2015 vs 2014 and 2016 vs 2015)

- "In" flux = Number of employees in N+1 year, not present in N year
- "Out" flux = Number of employees in N year, not present in N+1 year

In this case the result is:
 - for 2015 - In flux: 2 (ID:5,6 that were not present in the previous year). Out flux: 1 (ID:4 that was present in the previous year but now not present)
 - For 2016 - In flux: 2 (ID:7,8 that were not present in the previous year). Out flux: 1 (ID:5 that was present in the previous year but now not present)

The simplest way to do it should be using a calculated column, but I cannot write it:

```
InFlux column: UniqueCount([IDEmployee]) OVER ([Year]) - UniqueCount([IDEmployee]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([Year]))
OutFlux column: UniqueCount([IDEmployee]) OVER ([Year]) - UniqueCount([IDEmployee]) OVER (NextPeriod([Year]))
```

Any suggestion?
Many thanks,
Lollone

Comment: @Lollone- Could you explain the expected output in excel and post it? It is little unclear as what you want to achieve here.

Comment: @ksp585 I've added a description in the post. Let me know if it is still unclear. Many thanks! :)

Comment: @Lollone- Please check the solution posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lollone- Please check the below solution and let me know if it works for all possible scenarios.

**In-flux column:**

```
If(Count([ID]) over (intersect(previousperiod([Year]),[ID]))=0,"In")
```

**Out-flux column:**

```
If(([Year]!=Max([Year])) and (Count([ID]) over (intersect(nextperiod([Year]),[ID]))=0),"Out")
```

**Final output:**

[image]